# how to use sftp connection to send files to remote server using public key/private key(non password) in informatica?

Tags: sftp, informatica

I meet some trouble in using sftp connection in informatica.

I don't use passwords and use public/private key files generated in remote server in sftp connection.

when I run the session, below message returns in monitor :

```
Severity: DEBUG
Timestamp: 10/19/2020 2:58:06 PM
Node: node-XXXXXXXX
Thread: WRITER_1_*_1
Process ID: 26993
Message Code: FTP_14084
Message: Unable to access the private key or public key file. Verify that the correct file path was specified.
```

does any body can explain why? many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the keys to the file for the user that is running informatica process. Please ask informatica admin to set it up by following below steps.

a) Check which user is running informatica process ( will assume its 'infa'). Logged in Server An with user Id 'infa' and corresponding password.

b) Create the keys in server 'source' with the following command.
/user/local/bin/ssh-keygen -t rsa

c) Copy the 'id_rsa.pub' file to 'authorized_key' file in ~/.ssh directory in serber 'remote'

d) Grant 777 privileges to authorized_key file in server 'remote'

e) Log into 'remote' with 'sftp_user' user ID( will assume its 'sftp_user'). use `cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys` to append the keys.

f) change permissions of below file and directory. Pls note they are very sensitive to permissions.
`chmod 600 authorized_keys`
`chmod 700 .ssh`

g) log into 'source' server using 'infa' and execute the sftp command in source server to verify-
`sftp sftp_user@remote`

Comment: this is about configuiration on linux, not on informatica

Comment: You are trying to sftp which needs linux config chnages/addition. and its not really config changes its adding your key to the server - like your friend giving you the keys to their home so you can get in as and when you want..